# SaltStack and Vagrant adding files

Tags: vagrant, salt

I use file.managed to add a file:

```
/home/vagrant/.bash_profile:
  file.append:
    - name: /home/vagrant/.bash_profile
    - source: salt://config/user/.bash_profile
    - user: vagrant
    - group: vagrant
    - template: jinja
    - mode: 0775
    - replace: true
```

The file is added; however the file is owned by root/root and does not change to by owned by vagrant.

Using Vagrant 1.8.5.
Salt is configured to be masterless and file client is local.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually using file.managed, you are using file.append - so salt is expecting to add onto the end of an existing file. This may be the cause of your issue. Instead try:

```
/home/vagrant/.bash_profile:
  file.managed:
    - name: /home/vagrant/.bash_profile
    - source: salt://config/user/.bash_profile
    - mode: 0775
    - user: vagrant
    - group: vagrant
    - template: jinja
    - replace: true
```

Also, be sure you are using the [latest version](https://repo.saltstack.com/) of Salt Stack, 2016.11